# put the contents of one field into another field upon form submit

Tags: 8

how can I add a field to a form submission upon submit that will have the same value as the field name "mail" but with the name "email"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Drupal 8 I did it this way, there may be a shorter way though

```
$value=$form_state->getValue('field_name');
$number=($value[0]['value']);
$form_state->setValue('other_field',$number);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it'll work if you implement hook_form_submit() hook for this form, and in that function set the value of one field to another.

E.g.,

```
FORM_ID_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  $form_state['values']['email'] = $form_state['values']['mail']; 
}
```

If your fields are fields of a content then replace the above line with this:

`$form_state['values']['email']['und'][0]['value'] = $form_state['values']['mail']['und'][0]['value'];`

Comment: the form submit when i put in this code doesnt seem to be reach.  It goes to the page that I have marked as the form action and never gets there.

Comment: this doesnt work for drupal 8

Comment: My bad, didn't realize you were asking for Drupal8. Sorry can't help. Haven't looked into Drupal8 yet.